# How to use Shell Parameter Expansion in Perl?

Tags: bash, perl, parameter-expansion

I am trying to implement a Bash parameter expansion technique to replace the existing extension of a file in a Perl script.

This is my bash code for replacing the file extension which is working fine:

```
mv "$f" "${f%.*}.png"
```

On the other hand, I am trying to use it inside a Perl script using `system()`:

```
system('mv', "$a/$fileName", "$a/${fileName%.*}".'.png');
```

`$a` holds the directory name which is being passed via command-line argument.

It throws `"syntax error near %"` followed by `"missing right curly or square bracket within string"`. There's no EOF in the error message.

When I do not use `%.*` then it simply appends `.png` after the existing file ending but it does not replace. Some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass Shell parameters to Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973285/how-do-i-pass-shell-parameters-to-perl-script)

Comment: Also check --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964536/accessing-shell-variable-in-a-perl-program

Comment: The multi-argument form of `system` does not run a shell at all, so no shell syntax whatsoever is honored. Anyhow, why would you use shell PEs when you have Perl? Perl is far more expressive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. I am new to Perl and Bash scripting. I managed to perform the task in bash but I am not able to achieve the task in Perl. Is there any solution to this.?

Comment: Use `move` from the core [`File:: Copy`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/File/Copy.html) module, which, unlike [`rename`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/rename.html) will even work across filesystem boundaries.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for the information. I used move: `move("$a/$fileName", "$a/$fileName".'.png');`. It simply appends the `.png` in addition to existing extension. Like `Paper.p.png`. I need to replace `.p` with `.png`.

Comment: Well, the quick and dirty way (NOT recommended) if you're on an unix-like system would be to use `system('bash -c mv', "$a/$fileName", "$a/${fileName%.*}".'.png');`, but it's very dirty and no-one should do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy According to https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html it doesn't use a shell only `If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument`, otherwise it's passed to `/bin/sh -c ` on unix platforms

Comment: Hi @ChatterOne. The NOT recommended way is giving the same error as mine. It has a problem with `%` symbol.

Comment: First of all, there is no guarantee that `system` will use `bash`, so if you want to make sure that you have `bash` executing the code, you should do it explicitly. But since you do have parameter expansion in Perl (not in the full extent as available in _bash_, but at least to the extent as available in POSIX shellx) using the [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function, you could consider writing your code completely inside Perl, without creating a child process.

Comment: Hi @user1934428. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @LeonS.Kennedy I didn't test it, so I'm not surprised that there's something to fix. Probably a bit of escaping would make it work, but you have a much better way of doing it in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you wish to replace the extension -- to change a filename.  There is no reason to reach for the shell for that once you are in a Perl script.

Changing an extension is easily done "by hand" (see below for libraries). With regex

```
my $new_filename = $filename =~ s/.*\.\K.*/$new_extension/r;
```

The `.*` greedily matches up to the very last `.` (that follows in the pattern), and `\K` then drops all matches so that we replace only what follows after it. Or, use the end-of-string anchor `$`

```
my $new_filename = $filename =~ s/\.\K[^.]+$/$new_extension/r;
```

what matches, and replaces, all non-`.` characters at the end of the string after a `.`.
In both cases the modifier `/r` makes it return the new string and leave the original unchanged; without it the string (`$filename`) would be changed in-place.

Now change the name of the file on disk.  A standard tool is [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)

```
use File::Copy qw(move);

move $filename, $new_filename  or die "Can't move: $!";
```

(If you notice the builtin [rename](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) stay calm and walk past it. See its linked page for reasons.)

---

The most solid way in general is by using suitable libraries of course, and there are good ones that can be leveraged for this.  Here it is with the useful [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) (which you need to install)

```
use Path::Tiny;

my $path = path($filename);

my $new_fqn = $path->parent->child( $path->basename(qr/[^.]+/) . $new_ext );
```

See linked documentation for this module but here is a brief explanation of the above.

The method `parent` returns the path up to the last component (file/directory), as a `Path::Tiny` object. Then the method `child` called on it adds another component to it.

For that we get the `basename` (the last component, with the extension stripped in this use), and then append the new extension to it. And voila, we get back the whole path with the extension replaced.  This does parse the path twice, once for `parent` and once for `basename`.

An additional benefit of this is that the module has a `move` method as well, so

```
$path->move($new_fqn);
```

finishes the job.

The module checks for errors and either `croaks` or throws an exception of [its own class](https://metacpan.org/release/Path-Tiny/source/lib/Path/Tiny.pm#L2129).

---

The old and tried UNIX way is by using the core [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

```
use File::Basename;

my ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($filename, qr/\.[^.]*/); 

my $new_fqn = "$path/$name.$new_ext";
```

Then use `File::Copy::move` to rename the file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will implement your solution. Please do not delete your answer. Many Thanks!

Comment: @LeonS.Kennedy I'll only add to it, a couple more ways to do this :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort and explanation. It worked, Finally. Earlier, when I enclosed the move function in brackets then it was giving an error `"Useless use of private variable in void context"` then I removed the brackets and it ran. Any idea why it was saying "useless use"? Anyways, it worked. Many Thanks!!!

Comment: @LeonS.Kennedy hm ... how precisely did you "enclose" ?  it should work with parens of course (I just find it cleaner without them, that's why I leave them out).  thank you for attribution -- stay tuned, I'm about to add...

Comment: At first I did like `move ("$a/$fileName", "$a/$new_filename" or die "Can't move: $!");` in addition to "useless use" error it was also saying `Usage: move(FROM, TO)` error. Then I removed the parentheses and it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: @LeonS.Kennedy Ah -- need `move($old, $new)  or die "...";`  The `die` is `or`-ed with the `move(...)` (the way you had it it's `move $old, $new-or-die`).  Added more to the post.

Comment: Thanks! I will observe your solution with more precision. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Bash and Perl syntax at the same time, both langauge has obscure syntax, using them at the same time make things worse.

Bash:

```
"${f%.*}.png"
```

Perl:
Use File::Basename module https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html

```
$f_new=fileparse($f_old,qr/\.[^.]*/);
$f_new.=".png";
```

Bash:

```
mv
```

Perl:

```
rename / File::Copy (see comment)
```

Put together(demo in one-line-Perl):
To Rename foo.jpg to foo.png

Using rename:

```
$ perl -MFile::Basename -e '$f_old=$ARGV[0];$f_new=fileparse($f_old,qr/\.[^.]*/);$f_new.=".png";rename $f_old, $f_new' foo.jpg
```

Using File::Copy

```
$ perl -MFile::Copy -MFile::Basename -e '$f_old=$ARGV[0];$f_new=fileparse($f_old,qr/\.[^.]*/);$f_new.=".png";File::Copy::move $f_old, $f_new' foo.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to Perl and I am understanding your answer and implementing it bit by bit.

Comment: That use (`fileparse($f_old,qr/\.[^.]*/);`) returns only the bare name (without extension), without the path.  That's not good for renaming files. Also, I'd recommend against `rename` -- way too many details to account for. See docs for it.

Comment: @zdim Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer a bit. I have not used Perl for a while, seems TIMTOWTDI days has gone :)

Comment: An interesting point! While TIMTOWTDI is alive and well of course, I'd say that indeed people now make a distinction that some ways are better than others.  (note: way**s**. plural :)

Comment: @zdim Agree! and perlers are always kind :)

Answer (score 0):

You have double-quoted strings in Perl, which means that `$variables` are interpolated inside **Perl**. It is like writing in Perl

```
my $xx="abc"
my $yy=${xx%.*}
```

You would get the same error.